# How to return a list from a join instead of separate entries per occurance?

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-2.0

Working on an EF Core 2 project.  I am not sure how to word my question but will give it a try.  I have three tables

```
Order {
    Id : int
}
LineItem {
    Id : int,
    OrderId : int (fk),
    ProductId : int (fk),
    FriendlyId : string
}
Product {
    Id : int,
    Name : string
}
```

I am trying to create a view model that will return a json or order details with a list of strings for LineItem.FriendlyId and Product.Name as so:

```
OrderListViewModel {
    Id : Order.Id,
    LineItems : string[] of LineItem.FriendlyId,
    Products : string[] of Product.Name
}
```

The order technically has several other fields that I can join perfectly fine as there are only one per order but for these I do not understand the best approach to get the lists from a single query to the db.  I can write functions that build the strings but it takes much longer and I believe as they are related there is a quicker way to make a single query.

Right now my query is similar to:

```
var orderList = (from orders in _context.Orders
  join lineItems in _context.LineItems on orders.Id equals lineItems.OrderId,
  join products in _context.Products on lineItems.ProductId equals Product.Id
  ...several other joins...
select new
{
   id = order.Id,
   ... join entries that are suppose to be one item returns ...,
   lineItems = (new string[] { } ),
   products = (new string[] { })
}
```

The above works in less than a minute.  If I take out the two joins for product and lineitem, then use I believe EF Cores relations as so: orders.LineItems into a helper function to build the strings, it takes several minutes (more than ten).

```
lineItems = GetFriendlyIds(orders.LineItems);
products = GetProducts(orders.LineItems);
```

Type of thing, which I can get to return the right strings in an unreasonable amount of time due to the separate calls per order.

I haven't been able to word my questions for google or stackoverflow to find an example similar enough to puzzle together but I'm sure there are examples out there.  I appreciate any help or insight provided, and I thank everyone for their time!

Happy Wednesday.

Comment: Hi, can you modify your "working query" example to be more realistic, i.e. actually compile and produce the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Using the navigation properties is actually the preferred way in LINQ to Entities queries over manual joins, since they really represent (and are translated to) joins with a proper cardinality (see [Don’t use Linq’s Join. Navigate!](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/)).

For example, instead of

```
from order in _context.Orders
join lineItem in _context.LineItems on order.Id equals lineItem.OrderId
join product in _context.Products on lineItem.ProductId equals product.Id
```

you could use the equivalent

```
from order in _context.Orders
from lineItem in order.LineItems
let product = lineItem.Product
```

Note that the `let` statement is optional, just to keep the same variables as in the join example. Navigation properties can be used directly with `.` notation like if they were objects, so to get the product name you could simply write `lineItem.Product.Name`.

Now on the real problem - *"a helper function to build the strings"*. Don't use helper functions inside LINQ to Entities queries - they cannot be translated to SQL. EF6 simply throws `NotSupportedException` while EF Core does so called [client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval). While it "works", the performance in general suffers (as you already encountered). For more info, see [How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/overview).

The solution is to build the query without using custom methods:

```
var query = 
    from order in _context.Orders
    select new OrderListViewModel
    {
        Id = order.Id,
        LineItems = order.LineItems.Select(lineItem => lineItem.FriendlyId).ToArray(),
        Products = order.LineItems.Select(lineItem => lineItem.Product.Name).ToArray(),
    };
```

As you can see, the query is straightforward and naturally following the entity model and relationships.

Note that since the resulting `LineItems` and `Products` are produced with correlated subqueries, depending on the EF Core version the execution of the query (when you call `query.ToList()` or similar) will actually execute N + 1 SQL queries in pre 2.1 versions and 3 SQL queries in 2.1+ versions (see [Optimization of correlated subqueries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#optimization-of-correlated-subqueries) in [New features in EF Core 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1). So it's highly recommended to upgrade to the latest EF Core version.